# Expresión regular que valide 15 números separados por punto

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes de partida soy nuevo en la programación y quiero realizar una consulta sobre una expresión regular que me valide el siguiente número.

100.000.000.000.000
en total son 15 números los (.) deben ser opcionales.

y estoy ocupando la siguiente expresión:

```
/^[\d{3}]*[\.]*[\d{3}]*[\.]*[\d{3}]*[\.]*[\d{3}]*[\.]*[\d{3}]*$/
```

si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería.

Comment: ¿es necesario que sea una expresión regular?

Comment: Lamentablemente si..

Comment: puedes eliminar `[\.]*` y cambiarlos por `\.?`, ya que solo te estás ocupado de un carácter, y ese caracter puede estar una única vez (o no), eso lo realiza el `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás marcando tanto los grupos de tres dígitos como los puntos de forma opcional (con el `*`), pero también permites que se repitan (`*` significa 0 o más).

En en el caso del número de 15 dígitos separado por puntos, se trata de cuatro grupos de 3 dígitos y un punto y finalmente un último grupo de tres dígitos más.

```
^([\d]{3}\.?){4}[\d]{3}$
```

`^` Inicio de la cadena.
`[\d]` cualquier dígito.
`[\d]{3}` grupo de tres dígitos cualquiera.
`[\d]{3}\.?` grupo de tres dígitos cualquiera seguido de un punto opcional.
`([\d]{3}\.){4}` cuatro grupos como el anterior descrito.
Finalmente, el último grupo de tres dígitos `[\d]{3}` y el final de la cadena `$`.

[Aquí](https://regexr.com/5589p) te dejo el ejemplo para que puedas hacer pruebas.

---

**EDIT:** ¿Cómo modificarla para que cumpla con números más pequeños que 15 dígitos?

Vamos a tener que sacar otro grupo delante para determinar los primeros 3 dígitos.
Los primeros tres dígitos son de la forma `[1-9][\d]{0,2}`.

A este primer grupo de uno a tres dígitos le seguirán los grupos de tres dígitos. Podrán haber de cero a cuatro grupos de tres dígitos y, ahora, pondremos el punto delante de cada grupo de tres dígitos que separará el primer grupo con los otros.
La expresión queda así

```
^[1-9][\d]{0,2}(\.?[\d]{3}){0,4}$
```

Para controlar el caso del 0, lo podemos tratar por separado. También los negativos

```
^(-?[1-9][\d]{0,2}(\.?[\d]{3}){0,4}|0)$
```

Con esto, voy a dar la pregunta por respondida.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Estimado.                                                                                                                               Gracias por tu respuesta era justo lo que buscaba..tengo solo una duda ahora si quisiera que la expresión me permita ingresar números menores a 15 dígitos y solo se gatille cuando supere los 15 dígitos. como tendría que hacerlo de antemano te agradezco tu ayuda.

Comment: Se complica bastante... Voy a ampliar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias VRoxa

Comment: Gracias @VRoxa quedo excelente!!!!!!!!!

Comment: deberían sacar los rangos `[\d]` y remplazarlos simplemente por `\d`, ya que son incecesarios los corchetes cuando se tiene un único elemento dentro

Comment: Gracias Isaac lo aplicare!!

Comment: Hola, @IsaacNewton. Sí, lo sé. Me gusta ponerlo así porque considero que se lee mejor. Mero gusto personal...